# How to combine 2 ints to make a unique dictionary key

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

I am trying to make a dictionary key from 2 ints, I am thinking to combine them as follows
2 and 3 ---> 23
21 and 34 ---> 2134
etc etc

How would one acheive this, and if this is a bad approach, what would be better?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first problem you'll encounter with this scheme is the collisions between for example, (2,134) and (21,34) and (213,4).

Comment: Ah, I didnt actually consider that. Thank you

Comment: Make a class that has two ints as properties and make that your key.

Comment: You could change the key data type to string?...and then combine them with a delimiter: `21,34`

Comment: Thanks all for the advice. This is for a fluid simulation and thus the option with the smallest performance hit is needed. Does anyone know which would be faster of the suggested methods?

Comment: @KMoore I did some performance tests and updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following struct combines two integers and overrides equality members to make it usable as key in a dictionary. This solution is faster than my previous proposal using a `Tuple<T1,T2>` and less error prone than using a `long`.

```
public struct IntKey
{
    private readonly int first;
    private readonly int second;

    public int First { get { return first; } }
    public int Second { get { return second; } }

    public IntKey(int first, int second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public bool Equals(IntKey other)
    {
        return this.first == other.first && this.second == other.second;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return obj is IntKey && Equals((IntKey) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (this.first*397) ^ this.second;
        }
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class DictionaryTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<IntKey, string>();

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            dictionary.Clear();
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                dictionary.Add(new IntKey(i, i), "asdf");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            watch.Restart();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                var value = dictionary[new IntKey(i, i)];
            }

            Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Try it. 1,000,000 writes or reads take about 250ms on my Azure VM.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is great. Only one question. How would I then get the x and y from the key?

Comment: I added some getters. See modified answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the max value for your int number, say 256 then you can do

firstInt * 256 + secondInt

the above will give you unique number with the performance benefit of the int.

Just reverse the calculation to get back the two numbers